# How to write UNION in Doctrine 2.0

Tags: sql, union, doctrine-orm

How to write this SQL query in Doctrine 2.0 (and fetch results)?

```
(SELECT 'group' AS type, 
    CONCAT(u.firstname, " ", u.surname) as fullname, 
    g.name AS subject,
    user_id, 
    who_id, 
    group_id AS subject_id,
    created 
  FROM group_notification 
  JOIN users u ON(who_id = u.id) 
  JOIN groups g ON(group_id = g.id)
)

   UNION 

(SELECT 'event' AS type, 
    CONCAT(u.firstname, " ", u.surname) as fullname, 
    e.name AS subject, 
    user_id, 
    who_id, 
    event_id AS subject_id, 
    created 
  FROM event_notification 
  JOIN users u ON(who_id = u.id) 
  JOIN events e ON(event_id = e.id)
)
   ORDER BY created
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, I found maybe the best solution:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({"group" = "NotificationGroup", "event" = "NotificationEvent"})
 */
class Notification {
   // ...
}
```

And then two classes (*NotificationGroup* and *NotificationEvent*) extending *Notification*:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 */
class NotificationGroup extends Notification {
    //...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class NotificationEvent extends Notification {
    //...
}
```

Comment: And how is the explanation to this solution?

Comment: @ihsan you select from the base class repository (`Notification`) and you get all the objects of that are of subclass type (`NotificationGroup`, `NotificationEvent`, and even just `Notification` if you haven't declared it abstract). If you need only certain types, then you can use the `INSTANCE OF` operator in WHERE.

Comment: Would this approach in fact create a UNION SELECT query?

Comment: @Daniel Böttner, no. It will use table joins. https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Answer (score 12):

UNION is not supported in DQL, but you can still write a UNION query and use the Native Query capabilities to retrieve the data:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/native-sql.html#native-sql

However from your example it seems you want to use some form of table per class inheritance,
which is not yet supported. There is another form of inheritance, (Joined Table Inheritance) that works though, if you can change your schema.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.16/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

A view would be another good solution, but then it depends on your database vendor if it also supports write operations or not.

Comment: @FrancescoCasula also broken :)

Answer (score 2):

`UNION` is not supported in Doctrine, s. the discussion [here](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5657#issuecomment-181228313).

Comment: As an interm solution you could use a VIEW to get UNION support.

Answer (score 2):

```
$connection = $em->getConnection();
$query = $connection->prepare("SELECT field1, field2 FROM table1 
                                UNION
                                SELECT field3, field4 FROM table2 
                                UNION 
                                SELECT field5, field6 FROM table3
                                ");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll();
```