# Concataine 2 doctrine repository in a single variable

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, repository, repository-pattern

Being a beginner with **Symfony** and **Doctrine** I have some difficulties to achieve what I would like.

Indeed I have 2 tables in my database : 'Prints' and 'Files'. I have 2 entities and 2 repositories.

These two tables are similar, we find almost the same variables in the entities.

I made the following code. Of course it works but I don't find it very "professional":

```
//we are in a new controller 


/**
     * @Route("/Admin/", name="Admin")
     */
    public function AdminAction(){

        $doctrine=$this->getDoctrine();
        $repositoryPrints =$doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Prints'); 
        $repositoryFiles =$doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:Files'); 
    
        $repositoryUser =$doctrine->getRepository('AppBundle:User'); 

        $showPrints = $repositoryPrints->findAll();
        $showFiles = $repositoryFiles->findAll();

        $owners = $repositoryUser->findAll();
        return $this->render('@App/Admin.html.twig', [
            'showPrints'=> $showPrints,
            'showFiles'=> $showFiles,
            'owners'=> $owners
        ]);
    }
```

This code makes me do a lot of repetitive code like this in my html/twig files :

```
//The Admin.html.twig file

{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block body %}
<table class="tableClass">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="head">Tilte</th>
      <th class="head">Owner</th>
      <th class="head">Size</th>
      <th class="head">Printing Duration</th>
      <th class="head">Due Date</th>
      <th class="headStatus">Status</th>
      {% set break = false %}

      {% for element in showPrints %}
          {% if element.done == 1 and break == false %}
          <th class="head">
            Date of print
          </th>     
            {% set break = true %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
       {% for element in showFiles %}
          {% if element.done == 1 and break == false %}
          <th class="head">
            Date of print
          </th>     
            {% set break = true %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %} 
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

A quick and easy solution would be to do this:

```
$showAll = $repositoryPrints->findAll() + $repositoryFiles->findAll();
```

instead of this :

```
$showPrints = $repositoryPrints->findAll();
$showFiles = $repositoryFiles->findAll();
```

In my controller.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this so easily?

Thank you for your attention and your potential answers.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Anything not working with your approach?

Comment: `{% for element in showPrints|merge(showFiles) %}`

Comment: first of all - why are this two seperate tables in the first place?  you could use single table inheritance - see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155288/how-to-write-union-in-doctrine-2-0 another "solution" may be to use a union join - https://gist.github.com/adamsafr/38ef86a9c52d7f258a2a7116f115628d

Comment: Nica Haase, yep i tried with this solution ("  $showAll = $repositoryPrints->findAll() + $repositoryFiles->findAll(); ") but it doesn't work at all, the merge-array solution was the easiest solution (for me).

Comment: Artem, yep thanks you for this answer, i didn't tested an interrested at array at all, i was focus on repository or twig solutions ... i prefer to use  merger_array in the contoller to have a cleaner code but thanks for your answer.

Comment: Rufinus, i've done the code in two times, the first time i needed a form with only input and selector, etc ... and in second time i needed to have a form with a upload and i did it in 2 forms so i was thinking about 2 entities and so -> 2 Tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAll()` function will return array. I think you can merge it using `array_merge` function.

```
$prints = $repositoryPrints->findAll();
$files = $repositoryFiles->findAll();

$showAll = array_merge($prints, $files);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I hadn't thought of this solution. It's been three days that I'm looking for "repository", "twig", and so on  This works perfectly and allows me to sort the "array".